# Problem combining two working codes in Python. Guessing i cant mix requests and requests-html modules

Tags: python

I started to code this over the weekend. After a ton of googling and watching youtubes I finally have one code to scrape google shopping results and another to upload it to airtable.

The scraping works on its own, so those the airtable one. But combined they dont. I belive it's because "r" is used in both.
Scraping uses requests-html while airtable code is using requests.
I tried to do the airtable post command with requests-html, but I dont even know if that can be done.
I read somewhere that my error code "shadows name 'r' from outer scope", meaning that one could be global and the other isn't. Then again I dont know how to fix that.

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTML, HTMLSession
import time

AIRTABLE_BASE_ID = "***"
AIRTABLE_API_KEY = "***"
AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME = "***"

endpoint = f'https://api.airtable.com/v0/{AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}/{AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME}'


def add_to_airtable(produkt_air="", retailer_air="", preis_air=""):
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {AIRTABLE_API_KEY}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
    data = {
        "records": [
            {
                "fields": {
                    "Produkt": produkt_air,
                    "Retailer": retailer_air,
                    "Preis": preis_air
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    r = requests.post(endpoint, json=data, headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
    return r.status_code == 200


session = HTMLSession()

with open('urls.txt', 'r') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        r = session.get(url)

        produktscan = r.html.find('title')
        produkt = produktscan[0].text
        produkt = produkt.replace(' | Google Shopping', '')

        for article in r.html.find('tr.sh-osd__offer-row'):
            retailer = article.find('div.kPMwsc', first=True).full_text
            retailer = retailer.replace('Wird in einem neuen Fenster geöffnet', '')
            preis = article.find('div.drzWO', first=True).text
            add_to_airtable(produkt_air=produkt, retailer_air=retailer, preis_air=preis)

            print(produkt)
            print(retailer)
            print(preis)

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: In general to fix shadowing varnames, just rename one of them.  But I don't see the shadow here.

Comment: Yep, there's no name collision going on here (unless I'm blind).  There's nothing wrong with having `r` inside a function and `r` in the global scope: python is lexically scoped and will just fail to see the global var in the fn (which is what you want).  What *exactly* doesn't work?  What are the errors?

Comment: The Problem ist, that posting the values to Airtable results into a 422 and the values arent posted in the table:
add_to_airtable(produkt_air=produkt, retailer_air=retailer, preis_air=preis)

The 422 is read here:
print(r.status_code)

Since i try to combine two separate working codes, when i run the Airtable code by it self it works great with that function. Thou i dont import requests-html in that single code snippet. I only load requests.
So i was wondering if maybe the two diffrent request import modules somehow collide?

Comment: if you add your individual scripts (exactly as they are when they work, but obviously hiding secrets) it should be easy to see what is going on .

The two requests modules will not collide: that's the beauty of python namespaces.

Comment: i found the problem. Inside Airtable the "Preis" column is formated as a currency field. 
i had to strip: preis = article.find('div.drzWO', first=True).text. And i had to turn it into a float.